# Speeding up template matching in opencv4android

Tags: android, opencv, templates, vision, template-matching

I'm using OpenCV4Android to try out template matching on an android phone. Essentially what I'm doing is taking a picture of some object that I wish to detect, cropping it and saving it as a template.

I then use my android camera and a surface view to constantly get images from the camera. I am then applying template matching on each image, converting the image to a Mat first. However, when applying template matching I only get around 3-4 fps.

What I am essentially doing is this:

```
           mCameraMat = inputFrame.rgba();

            int matchMethod = Imgproc.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED;

            // mTemplateMat resized in terms of video size in prepareMediaRecorder.
            // Very hacky solution so need to fix it!
            int result_cols = mCameraMat.cols() - mTemplateMat.cols() + 1;
            int result_rows = mCameraMat.rows() - mTemplateMat.rows() + 1;


            mResult = new Mat(result_rows, result_cols, CvType.CV_32F);

            // Move this to a new thread.
            Imgproc.matchTemplate(mCameraMat, mTemplateMat, mResult, matchMethod);
            Core.normalize(mResult, mResult, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());

            // Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc
            MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(mResult);

            Point matchLoc;
            if (matchMethod == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF || matchMethod == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED) {
                matchLoc = mmr.minLoc;
            } else {
                matchLoc = mmr.maxLoc;
            }


            // Draw a boundary around the detected object.
            Imgproc.rectangle(mCameraMat, matchLoc, new Point(matchLoc.x + mTemplateMat.cols(),
                matchLoc.y + mTemplateMat.rows()), new Scalar(TrackingActivity.r, TrackingActivity.g,
                TrackingActivity.b, TrackingActivity.a), 2);
```

Where mTemplateMat is the template bitmap image converted into a Mat object.

The bottleneck is on the line

```
Imgproc.matchTemplate(mCameraMat, mTemplateMat, mResult, matchMethod);
```

If I remove that line, I get around 25 fps, which is much more acceptable. I'd be fine with anything above 13-14. I understand that template matching is a very expensive process and doing it every frame can be costly. I have tried to do it every 20 frames, but it still slows down the processing considerably, and the end video looks worse as there is a constant transition from a smooth fps display to a low fps display.

What are my options in optimising matchTemplate? Any tips are much appreciated.

Comment: What are the dimensions of `mCameraMat` and `mTemplateMat`?

Comment: There seem to be two opportunities to influence the amount of work `matchTemplate` has to do. First would be changing the method used for comparison. As you can see in the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html#matchtemplate) each method corresponds to a different formula, and some of those look like they require less work to evaluate than others (Say `TM_CCORR` vs `TM_CCOEFF_NORMED`). The difference probably won't be too big. The other option is to use smaller inputs (say downscale the image).

Comment: @DanMašek, the dimensions of `mCameraMat` are 1280x720 always, `mTemplateMat` depends on the size of the template chosen, but is normally no more than half the size of `mCameraMat`. 

I've tried using different methods. Would downscaling the image not effect the end result? Ultimately, as each image comes in, I would have to downscale it, meaning I could be doing 10+ downscalings a second (depending on what fps is). 

If I do choose to downscale, should both the template and source image be scaled down by the same ratio? What would a good size be? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You would scale both by same amount. As to how much, that depends on what you're processing -- you need to experiment and see what works. Some sample images attached to your question would help. I would look at powers of 2, and a fast scaling method. In your case: image `(W,H)=(1280,720)` and template `(w,h)=(640,360)`. That means `(W-w+1)*(H-h+1)=641*361=231401` times evaluate the method function on a pair of 640x360 matrices. With input size 640x360 and template 320x180, you have 1/4 the evaluations, each processing 1/4 as many matrix elements.

Comment: ... some 170 thousand evaluations would definitely take much more time than even some high quality scaling of the image. | As to not making the video stutter, assuming the position of the object doesn't move much, you could fire off the template matching asynchronously. Once it's done, update the boundary coordinates, so they can be drawn over the next frame you get.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Could you elaborate what you mean by a "fast scaling method"? I would have just used the `resize` method built into OpenCV. Would you not recommend this? I have tried to move the template matching to a new thread, and the result was not very successful. I didn't try something like `Asynctask` - is this what you mean by firing it off asynchronously? I'd want to keep the template matching off the UI thread so I think using an `Asynctask` along with some downscaling would be a good combo. I very much appreciate the help.

Comment: Yeah, `resize` is fine, i meant something like `INTER_NEAREST` or `INTER_AREA` vs. say `INTER_LANCZOS4`. For the async part, I suppose, but I don't know Java well enough to give you concrete advice. One thing to be aware of is that openCV Mats use reference counting on their payload, and unless you make explicit copy you end up with shared state, which can bite you (in form of synchronization issues). | Oh and of course, once you the the matching on the downscaled image, you upscale the coordinates back to original scale, so you can draw over the original high-res image.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the heads up on using Mats, I'll investigate some potential solutions into this. Finally, I can't quite understand how you worked out that I would be doing 231000~ evaluations per image a few posts ago. Is there any documentation that describes this? Also, if you'd like, you can post an official answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: The related [OpenCV tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) has some explanation, and [`matchTemplate`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html?highlight=matchtemplate#matchtemplate) docs provide useful details as well. | I'll consider writing up an answer, but I like to write them detailed, so may take a bit ;)

Comment: That's fine by me, thanks :)

Comment: @DanMašek You said earlier "Oh and of course, once you the the matching on the downscaled image, you upscale the coordinates back to original scale, so you can draw over the original high-res image". I'm wondering if you could give an example of this? I've sped up template matching immensely, but the bounding box is drawn on the wrong location, and I believe I'm not upscaling the coordinates correctly.

Comment: Write a new question for that, along with example of your code.

Comment: Will do if I don't get it in the next 20~ mins. FWIW, I'm using the same code above, with the addition of creating 2 new Mats that hold the resized image. Thanks.